# Parse json to android applcation from data in mongodb by php web service

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, mongodb

I am looking to pull data from by mongodb by the use of php, then convert it to a json object which i can parse to my android applcation.

I can do this for mysql without any problems, but i am finding it hard to get the right format to be able to read to android.

If anyone has any advice tips or tutorials please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by finding it hard? You can't create JSON or you can't read JSON?

Comment: Finding it hard to read a Jason object which has been converted from mongo

Comment: Sorry.. but what do you mean by _"finding it hard"_? Either you are able to do it or you are not (boolean).. even if you are "finding it hard".. can you tell me what is the hard part?

Comment: It may sound simply but I can't pull my json object to my application. I can display it my php connecting to my mongodb bit I cannot display this data in my android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), a JSON parser to java objects. It's an easy-to-use library and in its web has a nice user guide.

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't know about Gson ill have a look at that